# JSON parse in swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm stuck on this one part of JSON. I'm using Firebase. Everything was working fine with the old code, then I decided to "nest" the company info inside the "campaign".

JSON:

```
"title" : "Somethign",
  "company" : {
    "iplydxT8UHhBfEKhZdAco5c5Luy1" : {
      "commany_image" : "url/to/company/image",
      "company_name" : "John Doe"
    }
  },
```

Swift 3 Model:

```
title = snapshotValue["title"] as! String
let companysnapshotValue = snapshotValue["company"] as! [String: AnyObject]
    for (key, value) in companysnapshotValue {
        let companysnapshotValue = companysnapshotValue[key] as! [String: AnyObject]
        company_name = companysnapshotValue["company_name"] as! String
    }
}
```

This part works great and I can get the `company_name`, however I get an error stating that I'm returning from initializer without initializing all stored objects.

This is how my code looked before. I was just saving the company name and image directly into the "campaign" Model. However I learned that to do this correctly, I should nest the company info inside the campaign. I also want to learn this so that I can apply it to other models. Help is much appreciated!

Old code:

```
title = snapshotValue["title"] as! String
company_name = snapshotValue["company_name"] as! String
company_image = snapshotValue["company_image"] as! String
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. I ended up just setting the company name and company images before the "for" statement and it worked out.